# <string.h> or <string>?

Tags: c++, string, string.h

Which is the best way to include the standard header string.h in a C++ project?
Using the [dot]h at the end, like this:

```
#include <string.h>
```

or just writing

```
#include <string>
```

Or, maybe, using another way that I don't know?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are actually different files. Yeah, it makes my head hurt too.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Those are two different headers.

- `<string>` is for c++ `std::string` class
- `<string.h>` is for c string functions (like `strlen()`, etc.), which should be `<cstring>` for c++ project (this is the third, you didn't know of).

Comment: -1 it's not a good idea to use `<cstring>` instead of `<string.h>`. it buys you nothing except added brittleness of the code, since `<cstring>` does not guarantee to not pollute the global namespace. having a non-polluted global namespace was the original motivation for `<cstring>`, but AFAIK no compilers implemented that, and with C++11 that guarantee is gone

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach, sure, I don't insist, you're free to use what pleases you.

Comment: @Michael: i was commenting on the answer, which currently says "which should be `<cstring>` for c++ project". that is dangerous dis-information. now that you have been made aware of the facts, you refuse to reconsider, which in a way is good: it means that readers can be sure that your advice is not grounded in any rational assessment.

Comment: You have a point here. And the point is that my advice should be considered in the light of your assessment of my personality grounded on my refusal to side with you in your crusade against the brittleness of the code as you see it and giving both of us freedom of choice instead. We'll leave it at that and let the reader decide.

Comment: In summary. If i need to use, in C, functions like "strcmp()" "strcat()" ecc, i have to use the C library '<string.h>'. On the contrary, if I'm programming in C++ lang, the standard says that I have to use the library of classes '<string>' or, if I need those functions, I have to use the '<cstring>' (that also is a library of classes). Right?

Comment: As Alf pointed out, you may choose to use <string.h> or <cstring> when using c++ and no, <cstring> is not a library of classes, but a fancy name for <string.h> for c++. In short, if you use strcmp(), strcat() family of functions you include <string.h> or <cstring> depending on the language and/or preferences, if you want to use std::string class, you include <string>.

Comment: Ok, understood. I'm using a "C with 'cin' and 'cout'" as my teacher says. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: @unNatural: It is likely that your teacher wants you to use `#include <string>`.  You probably *won't* need the functions in `string.h`, as `std::string` has largely the same functionality.

Comment: @Brian, I'd say "C with 'cin' and 'cout'" *may* mean no std::string.

Answer (score 8):

its quite different!

`<string.h>` this library for C-style strings

`<string>` for C++ strings

by standard in C++ you should use `<cstring>` instead `<string.h>`

Comment: -1 "by standard in C++ you should use <cstring> instead <string.h>" The C++ standard does not say that.

Comment: by using <cstring> you putting C-style string functions into `std` namespace, ok?

Comment: yes, which would be fine except you have no guarantee that they're not also being put in the global namespace. the upshot is then that code that works with one compiler may fail to compile with another compiler. not a very good idea

Answer (score 2):

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Standard_Library) says:

> The C++ Standard Library also incorporates 18 headers of the ISO C90 C
>   standard library ending with ".h", but their use is deprecated. All
>   other headers in the C++ Standard Library ***DO NOT*** end in ".h".
>
> Each header from the C Standard Library is included in the C++
>   Standard Library under a different name, generated by removing the .h,
>   and adding a 'c' at the start; for example, 'time.h' becomes 'ctime'.

Answer (score 1):

string is c++ stl headfile 
provide the template class ‘string’
string.h is c standard headfile
provide many function to use. like strlen strcpy memcpy.
if you want use in namespace std,which is not use globe namespace or not want to use string.h
you can use cstring instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `*.h` headers files are often C header files, that you can use in C++ perhaps with `extern "C" { ... }` wrapping

The headers without any `*.h` are usually genuine C++ headers.

It is a rule of thumb only.

The latest and previous C++ standards (c++11, C++03) define headers  like `<cstdio>` to wrap properly the original C headers, using namespaces, etc.

Comment: "The latest C++ standard"... well so did the previous one.

Answer (score -3):

The standard is

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Anonymous downvotes have the useful function of changing the ordering of the answers.  Anonymous downvotes are less useful than comments, but I don't consider them actively harmful.